# Calculate in dynamic created textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I add values in my dynamically created texbox in another textbox ? For example I have 6 textbox named from TextBox0 to TextBox6 and I want to add the values in TextBox0 to TextBox5 then set that values in TextBox6. How can I do that?

This is my code for create dynamic textbox:

```
static int column = 0;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;               
    if (column > 0)
    {
        do
        {
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.Text = "";
            tb.Name = "TextBox" + (i + column * 6);
            TextBox t = (TextBox)Controls["TextBox" + i.ToString()];
            Point p = new Point(15 + (column * 125), 5 + (i * 25));
            tb.Location = p;
            this.Controls.Add(tb);
            i++;
        } while (i <= 5);
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.Text = "";
            tb.Name = "TextBox" + i;
            TextBox t = (TextBox)Controls["TextBox" + i.ToString()];
            Point p = new Point(15, 5 + (i * 25));
            tb.Location = p;
            this.Controls.Add(tb);
            i++;
        } while (i <= 5);               
    }
    column++;
}
```

Comment: Why do you retrieve the newly created textbox from `Controls` before really adding them? You seem to have the skills of creating and retrieving the textboxes, so I am unsure what it really is you are after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private const string _textBoxName = "TextBox";
```

The method count textboxes sum by given range of text box ids. Be aware this will throw exception if the text box texts / name id are not intgeres or

```
   private int Count(int from, int to)
            {
                int GetIdFromTextBox(TextBox textBox) => int.Parse(new string(textBox.Name.Skip(_textBoxName.Length).ToArray()));

                var textBoxes = Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList();
                var textBoxesWithIds = textBoxes.Select(textBox => (textBox: textBox, id: GetIdFromTextBox(textBox))).ToList();

                var sum = textBoxesWithIds.Where(x => x.id >= from && x.id <= to).Sum(x => int.Parse(x.textBox.Text));

                return sum;
            }
```